# Transitive Dependency Errors When Upgrading Spring Boot To 2.1.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, hk2

I am trying to upgrade spring boot to the latest version 2.1.1. My java ee based web application uses spring framework, jersey and hk2 libraries too. Identifying the dependency versions from the [spring boot pom.xml](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.1.1.RELEASE/) we could see that it depends on spring framework 5.1.3 and jersey 2.27. Jersey libraries depend on hk2 libraries - namely org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject. Below are the jersey and hk2 libraries that our application uses

```
Jersey libraries
    1. org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server
    2. org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core
    3. org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client
    4. org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common
    5. org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava
    6. org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3
    7. org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet
    8. org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb
    9. org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson
    10. org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering
HK2 libraries
    1. org.glassfish.hk2:spring-bridge
    2. org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api
    3. org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils
    4. org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator
    5. org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject
    6. org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged
```

Most of the jersey libraries are at version 2.27 except the two libraries - org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava & org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3. Their latest version is 2.25.1.

For hk2 (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject), the latest version is 2.4.0.

1. How should we go about resolving the above dependency issues? For jersey, should we use the latest version i.e. 2.27 and for the non-existing ones we use their respective versions. Would that cause any issues?
2. Are there any best practices recommended for such situations?

I understand that we could rely on tests but I am trying to see if we could identify issues upfront.

Comment: I would personally go with the lastest version of hk2.  It is supposedly backward compatible and has been for a while, so you should be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution was to use jersey-spring4 dependency and remove the dependency to jersey-guava.